# How do i remove the last 5 characters in a string?

Tags: c#, string, substring

I was trying to remove the last 5 characters in a string but i'm having a error

```
  string a = "192.168.0.225:5010";
  int b = a.Length;
  string c = a.Substring(b, 5);

  MessageBox.Show(c.ToString());
```

---

> Error : Additional information: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.

Comment: Please try understanding about every line of code and what is it's output.

Comment: What do the parameters to `Substring` mean?

Comment: You should look at the [documentation for Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_), you are passing "Length" as the start parameter. The error is unclear, but you can't start the Substring passed the end  of the original.

Now if you are parsing IPs, you may want to use a regex or use Split instead of hardcoding the length of the port number: `string[] parts = a.Split(':');`

Answer (score 7):

You problems is the misunderstanding and usage of the *parameters* of  [`Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

The first parameter

> The zero-based starting character position of a substring in this
> instance.

The second parameter is

> The number of characters in the substring.

You would need to supply the `Length` of the string, minus the size that needed to be removed

```
string a = "192.168.0.225:5010";
var result = a.Substring(0, a.length - 5);

// or

var result = a.Substring(a.length - 5);
```

<sub>***Note** : This is a one way street to fail-town if the port size differs or is not available*</sub>

---

Another slightly more robust way would be to [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Split_System_Char___) by the port separator

> Splits a string into substrings that are based on the characters in
> the separator array.

```
var result = a?.Split(':')[0]
```

<sub>***Note** : This will work even if no port is supplied and return null on a null string, and the string if no port is supplied*</sub>

---

Or, if you are using .Net Core 3+ you could take advantage of [`IPEndPoint.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipendpoint.parse?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_IPEndPoint_Parse_System_String_) then call `Address`

> Converts an IP network endpoint (address and port) represented as a
> string to an IPEndPoint instance.

```
var result = IPEndPoint.Parse(a).Address
```

<sub>***Note** : To add even more fault-tolerance you could use the [`IPEndPoint.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipendpoint.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1) method*</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
  string a = "192.168.0.225:5010";
  int b = a.Length;
  string c = a.Substring(0, b-5); // change this

  MessageBox.Show(c);
```

Comment: Please don't write `c.ToString()` when `c` is a `string`.